# Classificação de palavras

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Estou tentando classificar as palavras de um *Dictionarie* extraido do **Tesseract** ao analisar uma imagem com textos padronizados como esses:

Obs: A coluna "CLASSIFICAÇÃO" foi adicionanda para ilustrar a classificação desejada. As linhas em branco são palavras indesejadas.

*Dictionnaire 1*:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| block_num | par_num | line_num | word_num | left | top  | width | height |      text       | CLASSIFICAÇÃO |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   51 |  150 |    76 |     56 | E,              |               |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  156 |  146 |   169 |     52 | Rafael          | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  354 |  147 |   260 |     51 | Bernardo        | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  639 |  147 |   215 |     51 | Silveira.       | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        5 |  879 |  149 |   120 |     49 | GPS:            |               |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        6 | 1024 |  149 |   460 |     57 | 753.553.554-20, | CPF           |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   50 |  236 |   203 |     65 | prcis           |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  279 |  236 |   226 |     51 | resolver        |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  526 |  251 |   120 |     36 | ese             |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  672 |  236 |   289 |     65 | problma.        |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  989 |  239 |   143 |     48 | Date:           |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        6 | 1157 |  238 |   334 |     56 | 02/01/2019      | DATA          |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   51 |  414 |   357 |     51 | Nascimento:     |               |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  433 |  416 |   334 |     56 | 24/07/1997      | NASCIMENTO    |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  913 |  414 |   175 |     66 | Sino:           |               |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        4 | 1116 |  416 |   131 |     49 | Ledo            | SIGNO         |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   51 |  594 |   134 |     49 | Mee:            |               |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  213 |  592 |   203 |     51 | Rebeca          | MÃE           |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  445 |  592 |   179 |     51 | Louise          | MÃE           |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  651 |  592 |   174 |     51 | Betina          | MÃE           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   51 |  681 |    93 |     51 | Pul:            |               |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  169 |  681 |   124 |     51 | Caio            | PAI           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  320 |  681 |   178 |     51 | Heitor          | PAI           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  522 |  684 |   227 |     48 | Lorenzo         | PAI           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  774 |  681 |   199 |     51 | Silveira        | PAI           |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   48 |  859 |   212 |     51 | idade:          |               |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  288 |  858 |   214 |     52 | Pindaré         | CIDADE        |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  529 |  859 |   162 |     50 | Mirim           | CIDADE        |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  719 |  888 |    18 |      4 | -               |               |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        5 |  765 |  862 |    96 |     47 | MA              | ESTADO        |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   51 |  948 |   279 |     64 | Endeco:         |               |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  358 |  951 |   101 |     48 | Rua             | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  485 |  948 |   222 |     59 | Grande,         | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  730 |  950 |   105 |     49 | 498             | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  861 |  977 |    18 |      4 | =               |               |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        6 |  904 |  950 |   193 |     49 | Centro          | BAIRRO        |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        1 |   51 | 1039 |    91 |     49 | :               |               |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        2 |  168 | 1039 |   373 |     49 | 32.622.441-5    | RG            |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        3 |  672 | 1039 |   111 |     49 | Cor:            |               |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        4 |  810 | 1037 |   185 |     66 | laranja         | COR           |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   51 | 1306 |   114 |     49 | Não             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  191 | 1303 |    63 |     52 | ha              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  281 | 1303 |   252 |     67 | ninguém         |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  559 | 1319 |   107 |     50 | que             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        5 |  689 | 1319 |   121 |     36 | ame             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        6 |  834 | 1319 |    27 |     36 | a               |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        7 |  886 | 1304 |    98 |     51 | dor             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        8 | 1007 | 1319 |    96 |     50 | por             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        9 | 1124 | 1304 |    37 |     51 | si              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       10 | 1186 | 1303 |    74 |     60 | sO,             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       11 | 1286 | 1319 |   106 |     50 | qUe             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       12 | 1416 | 1319 |    27 |     36 | a               |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       13 | 1490 | 1304 |   209 |     65 | busquE          |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   44 | 1404 |    29 |     36 | e               |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        2 |   97 | 1389 |   177 |     65 | qeira           |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  298 | 1388 |   144 |     60 | té-la,          |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  468 | 1389 |   403 |     65 | simplesmente    |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  897 | 1404 |    96 |     50 | por             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        6 | 1014 | 1404 |    83 |     36 | ser             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        7 | 1118 | 1389 |   139 |     51 | dor...          |               |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
```

*Dictionnaire 2*:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| block_num | par_num | line_num | word_num | left | top  | width | height |      text       | CLASSIFICAÇÃO |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  161 |   22 |   190 |     53 | Otavio          | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  372 |   22 |   174 |     53 | Victor          | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  566 |   25 |   196 |     49 | Castro.         | NOME          |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        5 |  787 |   25 |   120 |     49 | CPF:            |               |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        6 |  933 |   25 |   459 |     56 | 639.335.496-80, | CPF           |
|         1 |       1 |        1 |        7 | 1421 |   24 |   202 |     64 | preciso         |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   58 |  112 |   226 |     51 | resolver        |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  305 |  127 |   121 |     36 | esse            |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  451 |  112 |   289 |     65 | problema.       |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  768 |  115 |   143 |     49 | Data:           |               |
|         1 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  936 |  114 |   334 |     56 | 03/04/2019      | DATA          |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   59 |  289 |   357 |     52 | Nascimento:     |               |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  441 |  292 |   334 |     57 | 26/01/1997      | NASCIMENTO    |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  921 |  290 |   175 |     66 | Signo:          |               |
|         2 |       1 |        1 |        4 | 1120 |  289 |   227 |     66 | Aquario         | SIGNO         |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   59 |  470 |   135 |     49 | Mae:            |               |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  216 |  468 |   144 |     51 | Aline           | MÃE           |
|         3 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  384 |  470 |   120 |     49 | Sara            | MÃE           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   59 |  557 |    93 |     51 | Pai:            |               |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  180 |  555 |   106 |     53 | Luis            | PAI           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  312 |  557 |   165 |     51 | Pedro           | PAI           |
|         3 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  504 |  557 |   263 |     66 | Henrique        | PAI           |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   56 |  735 |   212 |     51 | Cidade:         |               |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  296 |  734 |   222 |     66 | Macapa          | CIDADE        |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  544 |  764 |    19 |      4 | -               |               |
|         4 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  586 |  737 |    77 |     48 | AP              | ESTADO        |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   59 |  824 |   279 |     64 | Endereco:       |               |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        2 |  361 |  824 |   231 |     51 | Avenida         | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  621 |  824 |   239 |     51 | Primeiro        | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  884 |  824 |    68 |     52 | de              | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  979 |  824 |   154 |     59 | Maio,           | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        6 | 1162 |  825 |    98 |     50 | 149             | ENDEREÇO      |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        7 | 1286 |  853 |    18 |      4 | -               |               |
|         4 |       1 |        2 |        8 | 1331 |  824 |   224 |     52 | Buritizal       | BAIRRO        |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        1 |   59 |  915 |    91 |     49 | RG:             |               |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        2 |  176 |  914 |   373 |     50 | 33.101.777-5    | RG            |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        3 |  680 |  915 |   112 |     49 | Cor:            |               |
|         4 |       1 |        3 |        4 |  814 |  914 |   159 |     50 | verde           | COR           |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        1 |   43 | 1203 |   114 |     48 | Nao             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        2 |  184 | 1199 |    61 |     51 | ha              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        3 |  273 | 1199 |   251 |     66 | ninguÃ©m        |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        4 |  552 | 1215 |   105 |     50 | que             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        5 |  682 | 1215 |   121 |     36 | ame             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        6 |  826 | 1215 |    27 |     36 | a               |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        7 |  878 | 1200 |    98 |     51 | dor             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        8 |  999 | 1215 |    97 |     50 | por             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |        9 | 1116 | 1200 |    36 |     51 | si              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       10 | 1179 | 1199 |    74 |     60 | s,              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       11 | 1278 | 1214 |   107 |     51 | que             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       12 | 1408 | 1215 |    27 |     36 | aA              |               |
|         5 |       1 |        1 |       13 | 1482 | 1200 |   210 |     65 | busque          |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        1 |   30 | 1298 |    30 |     36 | E               |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        2 |   83 | 1284 |   178 |     64 | queira          |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        3 |  285 | 1282 |   142 |     60 | te-la,          |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        4 |  455 | 1283 |   403 |     65 | simplesmente    |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        5 |  883 | 1298 |    95 |     50 | por             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        6 | 1000 | 1298 |    83 |     36 | ser             |               |
|         5 |       1 |        2 |        7 | 1104 | 1282 |   139 |     52 | dor...          |               |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+------+------+-------+--------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Tentei utilizar a biblioteca **Sklearn** para classificar um campo de cada vez, mas não sei dizer qual melhor modelo utilizar para meu conjunto de dados:  (linear, regressão,...)

Aqui esta o que eu tenho até agora :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

df = pd.read_csv("main.csv", sep=';', lineterminator='\r')

column = df.text.astype('category')
df['text'] = column.cat.codes

x = df[["block_num","par_num","line_num","word_num","left","top","width","height","text"]]
y = df['CLASSIFICAÇÃO']
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Sem dados de treino?

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de dicas para montas os dados de treino também, Pois como você pode ver, no meu possível dataset existem muito mais informações que são classificadas como "inúteis" (as linhas vazias do Dictionnaire), e isso pode acabar afetando o classificador

Comment: Cara... geralmente no campo de classificação em IA, a gente utiliza datsets de treino prontos, montar seu proprio dataset é complicado, minha experiencia é com classificacao de imagens, a proria `scikit` oferece datasets para isso. No seu caso o problema vai ser encontrar datasets pronto em portugues.

Comment: Existem varios sites na internet que oferecem varios tipos de datasets, um exemplo é o [gengo.ai](https://gengo.ai/datasets/the-best-25-datasets-for-natural-language-processing/), voce pode, tb, fazer buscas no [google dataset search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch)

Comment: Os dados já "existem", como eu disse no problema, é a saída do tesseract  ao ler uma imagem com um layout definido. A questão é otimizar a acurácia do classificador

Comment: Sim, sei que os dados ja existem, quando eu digo dataset eu me refiro ao dataset de **TREINO**, esse tipo de classificacao sem um dataset de treino se não é impossível, é inviável.

Comment: Uma sugestão seria pegar um dicionário, checar se cada palavra se encontra nele ou nao, se positivo classifique como um acerto, se não como um erro.

Comment: Olhando novamente o texto q vc apresenta, fica dificil dar uma sugestao, parece que vc quer classificar dentro de um contexto particular e não se o leitor leu errado ou não, sem conhecer as condiceos fica dificil